# What exactly is the point of adding childViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I got a parentViewController.

The parentViewController has 3 children.

AnnController,
BobController,
CharlieController

(not real name)

At any time only a view of one such controller may exist. Transition is done with:

```
[self transitionFromViewController:fromController toViewController:toViewController duration:duration options:options animations:animations completion:^(BOOL finished)
```

Everything works well.

But then what's the point of adding Ann, Bob, and Charlie as a child of Parent?

At first I thought it's so that viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear got called automatically during transitionFromViewController

But it's called anyway whether the viewController is a child or not.

It could be so that viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear got called when parents got called. But that's easy to do.

Of course, only the view that's actually in the view hiearchy of ParentController.view will have their viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear be called right? Or is it?

So what's exactly does the fact that Ann, Bob, and Charlie is the child of Parent Controller do?

At the Parent's viewWillAppear, will it go through all of it's child and call their viewWillAppear if and only if the childController's view is part of the hierarchy? Or what?

Actually what does the fact that

**Note:** I am well aware of what view containtment mean. I asked what exactly does it do? For example, one of the answer said that it pass on rotation. Yes. But does it do so for all child or only child whose view is in the parentViewController.view hierarchy? Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Anwwer:**
adding `childViewController` allow you to redirect events in a view controller to other controllers that has been defined has its children.

**Long Answer:**
`addChildViewController` is part of `iOS 5` and later. It is a feature called "`view controller containment`". The basic idea behind this is that you can embed your view controllers into other view controllers of your own. It is powerful because it allows you to write your own `tabViewController` or `customNavigationController` for e.g.

The main thing about `View controller containment` is that it tries to ensure that all contained view controllers will get the appropriate messages. An easy example will be when you rotate your device, if you didn't add the `addChildViewController` the rotation changes event won't be passed down to your view hierarchy.

The view cycle like the calls you are mentioning (`viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear`) are managed by the view controller so it is a different story.

Take a look to the official [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) to get a good understanding of the power of custom container controller.

Comment: I am well aware of what view containtment mean. I asked what exactly does it do?

Comment: You mean viewWillAppear has nothing to do with childViewController?

Comment: adding a childViewController will not imply a call to viewWillAppear it is just defining a controller as a child so events will be forwarded - rtfm :-)

Comment: events like what? Like viewWillAppear?

Comment: My view can't rotate anyway. So I shouldn't use childViewController?

Comment: No the events that are passed along to the childViewController are not limited to the rotation events so you should really use the addChildViewController method

Comment: Actually will the child viewWillAppear be called when the parents will appear if it's not a child?